# Regex in javascript to match either a url pattern or given string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex expression that will match either a url pattern or a given string `[MY_NAME]`
Separately both of them are pretty straight forward:

```
/^(http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/

/\[MY_NAME\]/
```

but I cannot combine them together in a single regex expression

Comment: use alternation :- `/^(http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$|\[MY_NAME\]/`

Comment: I actually tried this but used brackets, this was my mistake (^(http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$)|\[MY_NAME\]

Comment: you need to escape `[` and `]`

Comment: @rock321987 please answer below so I can mark it as resolved (if you like)

Comment: you can delete the question..its a minor mistake

Comment: seems like someone answered..so you can't delete it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pipe `|`:

`/^(?:(http|https):\/\/[^\s"]*|\[MY_NAME\])+$/`

I added parenthesis and an anti-selector `?:` (This is assuming you want to match either string exactly)

Also I added a `*` to help your regex match correctly (as-well as a couple of other minor changes)

Comment: This actually is not working well, because I don't want to allow "http://" only, but http://x